# Use AJAX SlideShowextender in ASP

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have created asp.net web page and on which i do used Slideshow extender of AJAX control toolkit.
I did same steps as mentioned at [here](http://www.netrostar.com/How-to-use-SlideShow-extender-from-ASP.NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit)
I can see the image control on my page designer but when i open the page in browser it does not show the image control at all.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome developer tools (F12) to see if there is any errors in javascript console.